# Creating "stable" bond with PYMOL

Tags: pymol

I want to create a lactam bridge (peptide bond) between two residues through their side chains, starting from the original peptide sequence (pdb file). I used the two functions from PYMOL "bond" and "fuse" to form this bond. "Bond" works fine but the bond is no longer there once I re-open the file (that what I mean by "stable"). "Fuse" does not show that bond at all.

Select residues
PYMOL> bond pk1, pk2
or PYMOL> fuse pk1, pk2

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Pymol won't automatically save data back into a pdb file. A simple way to save all the state that Pymol carries is by writing a .pse file. To create a pdb file with arbitrary bonds that will show up in Pymol you can add CONECT records. To do this you can just open the pdb file up with a text editor and add the record by hand.